# How do I implement Java Serializable interface for custom linkedlist(tree) object?

Tags: java, serializable

I am trying to write a populated tree to file using `ObjectOutputStream`, but I am getting `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

```
// build Huffman trie
HuffNode root = buildTrie(freq);

try{ 

    FileOutputStream saveFile=new FileOutputStream("SaveObj.sav");

    ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
    save.writeObject(root);
    save.close(); 

} catch(Exception exc){
    exc.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Here is my tree class

```
private class HuffNode implements Comparable<HuffNode> , Serializable {
private final char ch;
private final int freq;
private final HuffNode left, right;

HuffNode(char ch, int freq, HuffNode left, HuffNode right) {
    this.ch    = ch;
    this.freq  = freq;
    this.left  = left;
    this.right = right;
}

// is the node a leaf node?
private boolean isLeaf() {
    assert ((left == null) && (right == null)) || ((left != null) && (right != null));
    return (left == null) && (right == null);
}

// compare, based on frequency
public int compareTo(HuffNode that) {
    return this.freq - that.freq;
}}
```

Why the serialization not working?

Comment: Normally NotSerializableException comes with a message telling you which class it encounted which was not serializable. Can you post the full error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HuffNode` is an inner class of some other class you haven't shown us.

An instance of an inner class holds on to an instance of the enclosing class. If the enclosing class is not `Serializable` this will prevent an instance of the inner class from being serialized.

`HuffNode` should probably be a static nested class.

```
private static class HuffNode implements Comparable<HuffNode> , Serializable
```